# Magnific popup verticalFit doesn't work

Tags: jquery, lightbox, magnific-popup

I got some trouble with my Magnific lightbox. In my gallery I would like to show vertical pictures in full screen. I found the verticalFit option which seems to be therefore.

```
$('li.lightbox').magnificPopup({
       type: 'image',
       delegate: 'a',

       image:{
          verticalFit: true, // Fits image in area vertically
          tError: '<a href="%url%">The image</a> could not be loaded.'
       },

       gallery: { enabled: true },
       callbacks: {
               buildControls: function () {
               this.contentContainer.append(this.arrowLeft.add(this.arrowRight));
          }
       }
});
```

Unfortunately the vertical images are not fitting. Does anyone of you has experiences with this plugin, had the same issue or an idea how to fix this?

Here my [website](http://www.eric-schwab.de/test) where the problem occurs.

I appreciate your help! =)

Cheers
Eric

Answer (score 1):

After many hours of searching, the problem was super simple.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Somehow the 'l' of html disappeared and this caused many weird behavior of my code but no error message regarding this!!!

I am so glad that I saw it and totally ashamed to the same time.

Thanks anyway for everybody who put thoughts into this.

Eric